# How to combine/manage all aliases for the same org

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, org, commandline, cli, developer-org

I have a trailhead playground org (not a scratch org) for which I've created multiple aliases and now I'd like to know how I can keep one and delete all the others using the Salesforce CLI? Also, is there a command that allows renaming an org's alias?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To see all the orgs you have with the aliases associated use the command:

```
sfdx force:org:list
```

To see all aliases you set:

```
sfdx alias:list
```

To remove the alias alone, you can use the command:

```
sfdx alias:unset <aliasName1> <aliasName2> <aliasName3> ...
```

this will remove the alias, but keep the org.

If you want to remove the org you can logout of the org using:

```
sfdx force:auth:logout -u <aliasOrUsername>
```

this will remove it from your list until you authorize it again.

to rename an alias, you can use the command

```
sfdx alias:set <newAlias>=<usernameOrValue>
```

if the org already has an alias, I don't believe that the newAlias will override that alias displayed in your org list, so best way to go about it would be to first unset the alias for a username and then reset it as necessary.

hope that helps answer your question.

Links:

[Salesforce CLI Command Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference.htm)

[alias Namespace](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_alias.htm)

Comment: Love this answer, Thanks!!